# How do I debug a Dart console app in VS Code that's started with command line attributes?

Tags: dart, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I want to debug a Dart console app that I normally start via:

```
C:\MyFolder\dart-sdk\bin\dart.exe main4.dart 0 < revcomp-input100000000.txt
```

When I add a new launch configuration on VS Code it adds:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Dart",
            "type": "dart",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "bin/main.dart"
        },
    ]
}
```

It's unclear to me what I have to put in to declare that I want debugging and want it to pass `0 < revcomp-input100000000.txt` into the console app.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to pipe into the process spawned like this. I would recommend making your script also accept a filename as an argument (which you can put into the args field in the launch config) and reading it directly.